# Plant Identification- Just popped up in the pot!

Tags: identification

I have an indoor plant that I let rest for about a month this winter and now have started watering and putting it in the bright light to get ready for summer here in the Northeast U.S. I had it in this same pot now for about 2 years. In about another few weeks, I'll set it outside again.

This spring, however this mysterious plant popped up a few weeks ago and I don't know how to identify it. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance. Sue[image]

Comment: Does it have a smell? It reminds me a bit of mugwort, which has a distinctive odor.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a smell to it. It's really getting big now, no flowers or blossoms either. I'm keeping my eye on it for anything in particular I can add to my description and let you all know. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The leaf shape, with its deeply cleft lobes is quite typical of the Anemone family, particularly *A. virginiana*, *A. riparia* and *A. cylindrica* which grow wild in NE North America and can propagate from seeds. But really we need flowers to make a positive id.

Comment: Great, thank for the input. I'm going to transplant it to a pot of it's own and see how it grows and flowers. Nice experiment! I'll let you know! thank you! :)